# How to get MAC on Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Just what the title indicates:

How can I get the MAC address of the computer where the program runs on with Visual C++ ?

I got:

```
getManagerHostMAC.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetAdaptersInfo@8
```

with the function provided by: [Getting Machine's MAC Address -- Good Solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069855/getting-machines-mac-address-good-solution)

Comment: [This](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/networkinformation/article.php/c5451/Three-ways-to-get-your-MAC-address.htm) is pretty old but may be worth looking @.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Win32 [`GetAdaptersInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions both return MAC addresses, amongst other things.  Remember that a machine may have multiple network adapters installed, thus have multiple MAC addresses available.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link with Iphlpapi.lib.  In Visual Studio, just add it to the list of linker libraries in the Project Properties dialog.